# How to prevent node of another generic type or a raw node to be added to a BST?

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, raw-types

I am implementing a generic BST, which does not allow duplicates. I have created a `Node` class, which has the following definition:

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>>{
    private T value;
    // other stuff
}
```

With it I basically want that the values associated with a certain node are comparable with other values of the same type. Then I have also inside it the following `compareTo` method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node<T> o) {
    return value.compareTo(o.value);
}
```

Now, in the implementation of my BST, I have a problem regarding the acceptance of parameters. The BST has the following definition:

```
public class BinaryTreeSet<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node<T> root;
    // other stuff
}
```

As you can see, I am requiring that the generic type of the root is comparable with other values of the same generic type, i.e. `T extends Comparable<T>`. This seems all ok, until the implementation of my `add` method, which has the following signature:

```
public void add(Node<T> n) {...}
```

Nothing seems suspicious (at least for me), but if I have the following code:

```
BinaryTreeSet<String> t = new BinaryTreeSet<>();
t.add(new Node(12));  // Adding a raw Node (whose value is actually an integer)
```

It actually compiles, but it shouldn't, because I am instantiating a `BinaryTreeSet` of `String`s, so I should not be able to add numbers to the tree.

What am I doing wrong, and why? How can I make it not compile in these cases?

Comment: At least, there's a warning.

Comment: Java generics cannot deal with rawtypes. Never use rawtypes and you won't have this problem. Use rawtypes and ignore all compiler warnings and there is nothing the compiler can do to help you - in fact that is why there are rawtype compiler warnings...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would never use raw types, but maybe the clients of this class would, that's why I am asking if there's a way of preventing this behaviour...

Comment: AFAIK there's no way you could prevent this from within your code, but if you have any control over the build environment you might be able to get this to generate an error using `-Xlint:rawtypes` and `-Werror`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent this because Java does not preserve generic type information at runtime. When the program is executing `value` is an `Object`, and therefore *can* hold both an `Integer` and a `String`.

The solution in practice is to simply ban raw types from your code. There is almost never a reason to use them in modern Java applications, and then only in well-tested and restricted-visibility library code. Never application logic. `javac` already prints a warning if you should use raw types, and you would be wise not to ignore them.

As ApproachingDarknessFish notes you can force `javac` to fail if you use raw types by calling it like so:

```
javac -Xlint:rawtypes -Werror ....
```